# how can we add blank spaces between a number of integer which is then converted from a string?

Tags: python, api, integer

I am trying to make a program which takes in value from an api an I have coded it to reduce it to 1 single value. But then it is returning me 5 different values. But after even accepting that too, I am facing a problem in which I am not able to convert the data extracted from the API in integer form.

So this is my code:

```py
import requests
import json
import pprint
import time

url = "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1827200/fields/2.json?api_key=IVIRLPBRZ121YIGL&results=1"

def data_extraction():
response = requests.get(url).text # the raw data we get from the website
data = json.loads(response) # that data converted into json format

raw_feeds = data["feeds"]

feeds = []
feeds = (raw_feeds[0])

tds = feeds["field2"]

string_tds = str(tds)

print(string_tds)

string_tds = string_tds.replace("ppm", "")
string_tds = string_tds.replace("\n", "")
string_tds = string_tds.replace("\r", "")

int_tds = int(string_tds)
print(string_tds)

data_extraction()
```

I am trying to convert the `string_tds` value to an integer and even though it is converted into an integer, it has removed all the spacing between the values.

I want a favor from someone which can be done in 2 ways:

1. By making the no. of values it is returning to 1.
2. Getting spaces between the individual numbers when we print int_tds as we get in string_tds.

Comment: Akshat, please make sure the code runs (the function doesn't look to be indented).  Also, provide a sample invocation or results and desired results.  Also try removing commented blocks (if they are not related to the issue).

Comment: I was just about to add what Mark said.... I already removed the commented blocks and improved the formatting a bit, but I can only guess how your indentation should be. Please copy-paste your code into the question (between the backticks) after you have tested that it runs. And please try to create a [mre] by removing the requests stuff and providing sample data instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since the digit number of each numerical value is different (it has two or three digits), it is best to keep the values in a string having space between them, and whenever you want to have it as integer, then remove the space and change it to integer.

```
string_tds = string_tds.replace("ppm", " ")
string_tds = string_tds.replace("\n", "")
string_tds = string_tds.replace("\r", "")

print(string_tds) # to print in your desired way 
int_tds = int(string_tds.replace(' ', '')) # to have it as integer
```